# Unable to manage two outlets [nested]. At http://localhost:4200/index, inner outlet shows blank

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, router-outlet

I am heaving routing rules like this.

```
{ path: 'index', component: IndexComponent
    , children:
      [ 
        { path: '', redirectTo:'profile',pathMatch:'full'},
        { path: 'profile',  outlet: "inner", component: ProfileComponent },
// some other rules
      ]
}
```

here I am using two router outlests, primary & inner. Inside IndexComponent.html inner outlet is present.
When I use http://localhost:4200/index at URL, Only primary router-outlet works, inner does not get updated.
My expectation is to show ProfileComponent in inner router-outlet OR to redirect /index rule to /index/orders/(inner:profile) with using IndexComponent in primary router-outlet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
{ path: '', redirectTo:'/(inner:profile)',pathMatch:'full'}
```

But if you root path is empty or use lazy loaded module, You can follow this PR([angular/pull/25483](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/25483))

Comment: This type of rule is already written for other login purpose.